# Equivalency of Guice Provider in Spring

Tags: java, spring, guice

What is the equivalency of Guice's Provider in Spring?

Here is the Guice code I need to replace with Spring:

```java
public class MyProxyProvider implements Provider<MyProxy> {

    @Inject
    Config config;

    @Override
    public MyProxy get() {
        return new MyProxy(httpsclient, config.server, config.user, config.password, config.version);
    }

}
```

and here the binding is defined:

```java
public class MyModule implements Module {

    @Override
    public void configure(Binder g) {
        g.bind(MyProxy.class).toProvider(MyProxyProvider.class);
    }

}
```

Finally, my goal is use @Autowired for the proxy object as follows:

```java
public class ConnectionTest {

    @Autowired
    MyProxy proxy;
}
```

Also note, that MyProxy class in in the external jar file that cannot be modified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equivalent to the `Provider` of guice is the [`FactoryBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean) in Spring.

From the documentation:

> The FactoryBean interface is a point of pluggability into the Spring
>   IoC container's instantiation logic. If you have complex
>   initialization code that is better expressed in Java as opposed to a
>   (potentially) verbose amount of XML, you can create your own
>   FactoryBean, write the complex initialization inside that class, and
>   then plug your custom FactoryBean into the container.

**Sample**

```
public class MyFactoryBean implements FactoryBean<MyClassInterface> {

    @Override
    public MyClassInterface getObject() throws Exception {
        return new MyClassImplementation();
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return MyClassInterface.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

This is a good approach when you have external libraries and complex object creation to avoid long XML configuration to setup your beans.

In order to use it within your context, you could just provide it as a normal bean within your context XML like:

```
...
<bean id="myClass" class="foo.bar.MyFactoryBean" />
...
```

**BUT**, if your bean is quite simple to be instantiated (not lots of dependencies), you can setup it directly on the context XML like:

```
<bean id="myClass" class="foo.bar.MyClassImplementation" />
```

**Alternative**

If you use Spring 3 you could write a configuration class (class annotated with `@Configuration`) as documented [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-java). With this approach you could do something like:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MyClassInterface getMyClass() {
        return new MyClassImplementation();
    }

}
```

This would add your instance to spring context and let autowire it within other classes. But some configuration is required, and its quite easy following the documentation provided.

Comment: 3.14 same document: "Use an ApplicationContext unless you have a good reason for not doing so." FactoryBean is primarly for bacword compability

Comment: `FactoryBean` and `BeanFactory` are two different things ;) `BeanFactory` is section 3.8.3

Comment: @Java-Mentor. I followed your Sample and created *MyFactoryBean* class that implements *FactoryBean<MyProxy>* interface. Also I added `<bean id="proxy" class="foo.bar.MyProxy" />`. Still I am gettting: Error creating bean with name 'proxy' defined in class path resource [test-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed.

Comment: can you provide the stack-trace? Additionally please provide your source.

Comment: It worked! However, I had to define the bean a bit differently : `<bean id="proxy" class="foo.bar.MyFactoryBean" />`. Thanks for your hints what to do.

Comment: You were right, I just corrected the class name for the xml context.

Answer (score -1):

You don't use a provider in spring, but configure your class MyProxy as a stereotype. This can be done by annotating the class with @Component or @Service or some other kind of stereotype. And enable component scan for your package or it can be configured as a stereotype in applicationContext.xml

Comment: The problem is MyProxy is in the extern jar file so I cannot annotate it. I will update my question.

Comment: Then you can instansiate it in your applicationContext.xml wil crate example

Comment: You can extend MyProxy in your own code and then autowire that.